# C# namespace KerberosTime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kerberos

I'm trying to build a C# project in MS Visual Studio 2022 and it has KerberosTime references:

```
KerberosTime kerb_auth_time = new KerberosTime(auth_time);
```

As well as some other lines like

```
KerberosAuthorizationDataPACBuilder pac = new KerberosAuthorizationDataPACBuilder();
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to contact the guy who created the project and I haven't succeeded in finding a solution online. Can anyone help me with it? What C# library / NuGet package (or whatever) contains KerberosTime for C#? Where do I look for it? Just can't build a solution because of it..

I've tried installing different NuGet packages in MS Visual Studio, SDKs and modules, searching online didn't help either..

Comment: Check if [this project](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/sandbox-attacksurface-analysis-tools/tree/main/NtApiDotNet/Win32/Security/Authentication/Kerberos) has everything you need. Also a tip: in a google search use double quotes to force google to look for pages that 100% have the text in quotes. Searching for `"KerberosAuthorizationDataPACBuilder"` literally gives only one page result.

Comment: @LegkovIvan well, your answer helped me realize that i was using old version of this library without KerberosTime.cs lmao
thanks!
P.S. not sure how to mark your reply as the answer ;/